# CreateWaitableTimerEx and SetWaitableTimerEx with high resolution flag, name and callback. Bug or feature?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, timer

I try to use Windows high resolution waitable timer and completion routine.

1. If create a waitable timer (call `CreateWaitableTimerExW`) with a name and `CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION` flag, it returns `NULL` and error code 0x57 (87) "*wrong parameter*".
2. If create a waitable timer with the flag `CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION` and **without name**, it returns valid handle, then call `SetWaitableTimerEx` (or `SetWaitableTimer`) with completion routing it returns `FALSE` and error code 0x57 (87).
3. It works if call `CreateWaitableTimerExW` **without** `CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION` flag.

Here is an example to reproduce problems. In the following example, just uncomment your desired `CreateWaitableTimerExW` call to see the results.

The question: is it a bug or known feature? I didn't find anything in [MS documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) regarding high resolution timers, names and callbacks.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void TimerRoutine(LPVOID lpArgToCompletionRoutine, DWORD dwTimerLowValue, DWORD dwTimerHighValue)
{
    HANDLE* hEvent = static_cast<HANDLE*>(lpArgToCompletionRoutine);
    if (hEvent != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Test succeeded!\n";
        SetEvent(*hEvent);
    }
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int64_t COEFF{ -10'000 };
    constexpr int64_t TIMEOUT{ 5'000 };

    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, _T("AnEvent"));
    if (hEvent == nullptr)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Failed to create an event object, error code = " << err << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create high resolution waitable timer. Uncomment one of them and compare behavior.
    HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimerExW(nullptr, L"ATimer", CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION, TIMER_ALL_ACCESS);
    // HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimerExW(nullptr, nullptr, CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION, TIMER_ALL_ACCESS);
    // HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimerExW(nullptr, L"ATimer", 0, TIMER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (hTimer == nullptr)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Failed to create a high resolution waitable timer with a name, error code = " << err << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
        return -1;
    }

    // Set timer with callback, relative timeout.
    LARGE_INTEGER dueTime;
    dueTime.QuadPart = TIMEOUT * COEFF;
    if (SetWaitableTimerEx(hTimer, &dueTime, 0, &TimerRoutine, &hEvent, nullptr, 0) == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Failed to set timer, error code = " << err << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hTimer);
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
        return -1;
    }

    // Wait until event object is signaled from the timer callback.
    WaitForSingleObjectEx(hEvent, INFINITE, TRUE);

    CloseHandle(hTimer);
    CloseHandle(hEvent);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you use `CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION` created another timer object ( `IRTimer` ) which is different from `Timer`. the `IRTimer` not support name. also in call `SetWaitableTimerEx` all parameters, except `&dueTime` and `hTimer`  must be 0. so you can only wait on `hTimer` in case `IRTimer` but you can not set callback for it

Comment: @RbMm, thank you for comment. Good to know. Is `IRTimer` MS internal object? I never met description. My agenda is to use high resolution timer with a callback. Do you have any recommendation for that? I create a timer manager, which is able to start and handle multiple timers in own thread. If use `CreateWaitableTimer`, the continues timer with 50ms timeout is triggered each 60-64ms.

Comment: you can not use `IRTimer` with callback. you can only wait on `IRTimer` object (handle). so you need or not use callbacks. or not use `CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION`. this is *xor*. and `IRTimer` like, `Timer`, `Type`, `Directory`, `Section`.. - one from object types

Comment: @RbMm, this I've understood, thank you. My question is whether there is any other alternative high resolution timer with the callback?

Comment: if you not want in place wait for timer, possible use `ZwCreateWaitCompletionPacket` + `ZwAssociateWaitCompletionPacket`. you can create `WaitCompletionPacket` and associate it with timer handle. as result, when timer is signaled, the packet will be queued to iocp. only this is probably kill idea with high resolution. because callbacks/iocp reaction can be delayed. may be you really not need high resolution ? how you think, why high resolution timer not support callbacks?

Comment: @RbMm, thank you. I'll try to find the description of `ZwCreateWaitCompletionPacket` and `ZwAssociateWaitCompletionPacket` and see whether it helps.

Comment: you can it take from here - https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntzwapi_8h_source.html but i not sure that all processing will be aligned with "high resolution"

Comment: @RbMm, thank yo very much!